# How to use Youtube Player with modern UI in Android using YoutubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use Youtube Player in my android app. It is showing a old outdated UI for the player but in the samples its showing a modern UI. The only difference between the two apps is I am using YoutubePlayerSupportFragment instead of YoutubePlayerFragment. This is because i am using AppCompatActivity for Material Theme in pre lollipop devices.

I am getting the below statement in logs:

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI﹕ Cannot load modern controls UI. Upgrade to the latest version of the Android YouTube API.
```

How to overcome this problem ? I need the modern UI using Appcompat and YoutubePlayerSupportFragment

Comment: Coudl you add some of your code please?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. Please update if you find a solution

Comment: Same here, that's why I added a bounty to this one

Comment: I didn't find any solution yet!

Comment: i'm afraid it's not a matter of support or native Fragment .. i've converted the sample app in order to make it use support fragments.. but the player has still the modern UI :\

Comment: also just by exporting the same classes and resources in an Android Studio project the old UI comes back .. i guess AS messes up something

Comment: @PierfrancescoSoffritti: Are you sure it showed the modern ui ? because i tried the same for me modern ui didnt come

Comment: @Kalyan on eclipse, yes

Comment: @PierfrancescoSoffritti Can you please tell me how to disable or remove a Video icon which displayed at left bottom side of player which is for link of youtube?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found something that worked for me.

Set this before super.OnCreate() in the Activity your fragment is currently on:

getLayoutInflater().setFactory(this);

Comment: Awesome find! No idea why this is needed or what it does, but it worked! Google, if you are reading this, update the docs!

Comment: I'm assuming that if you use Support libs the default factories used are old. They're kinda forced and then when you explicitly state the factory you wanna use, it overrides that. I haven't read much about factories or what they actually do so this is pure assumption.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that **the YouTube APIs have yet to be updated**.

Consider this:

- the YouTube Android Player API (found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)) is just a bunch of remote `View`s that link to the official YouTube application, that needs to be installed on the device for it to work
- the YouTube app is now minSdk 15, meaning that `Fragment`s are natively supported
- as you mentioned, everything works with `YouTubePlayerFragment`, but not with `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`

I believe that the YouTube 'SDK' can directly import the player view from the YouTube app, taking advantage of the modern UI controls. However, support `Fragment`s require more actions on the SDK side, actions which are yet to be taken in the form of an update.

**TL;DR**

Your best bet is waiting for the YouTube APIs to be updated to a newer version.

---

**EDIT**

Looks like the YouTube SDK has just been updated to **1.2.2**! Head [over here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) to download it.

Comment: @dexor : Still i am getting the old ui :(

Comment: I tried the new youtube sdk version still no improvements!

Comment: I have posted a work-around here by using YouTubeBaseActivity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33585966/2029134